# Show each form and hide other form after selecting an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to make a dropdown list using `<select</select>` named Classification and it has 2 form, Resident and Business. If the user choose Resident option a form will show up after clicking the 1st option and if the user choose Business form a different form will show up.

I found this code from the internet:

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="form_1">Form 1</option>
    <option value="form_2">Form 2</option>
</select>

<form name="form_1" id="form_1" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value="1">
</form>

<form name="form_2" id="form_2" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" value="2">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {    
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings();
});
```

My problem is I want to show the form each. For example user choose Resident only Resident form will show up and the other form will be hidden.

Hope you can help me in my problem
Thanks in Advance (sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the `forms` in your `dom` and exclude the `form` to be shown, and `hide` it. Then show the `form` to be shown.

Try,

```
$("select").on("change", function() {    
  $('form').not("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
if( "#" + $(this).val() == 'form_1' ){
    $("#form_1").show();
    $("#form_2").hide();
}
else {
    $("#form_1").hide();
    $("#form_2").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").on("change", function() {    
  $(this).siblings('form:visible').hide(); // if blank option selected, all form will should be hide
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```